# AngularJS timeout AJAX call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, timeout, delay

On next example I modified event, so instead on button click now call is on-change:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="keywords" ng-change="search()"/>
```

[a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php](http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php)

How to add delay/timeout so the script waits a second before making AJAX call?
(i.e. to give the user time to finish typing before making call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the function [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) in your `search` scope.

Example :

```
function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $timeout(function(){

          /* Execute your script */

        }, 1000); //add timeout 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not worked as this:
/* Execute your script */
 alert('test');

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.3, just add a debounce option on the model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="keywords" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
```

Documentation on ngModelOptions:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions